# how to write a if statement to check if a value has been entered

Tags: php, if-statement

How would i go about writing a if statement to check if the value of a option menu is empty and if so not to show it.

```
<option value="">GUYS AND GIRLS</option>
```

if value has nothing in it it wont show this option in the select menu 
but if.

```
<option value="http://test.com">GUYS AND GIRLS</option>
```

It has something there it will show up in the drop down.

Comment: What have you tried?  Show us what you've tried, and we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: well im using a wordpress plugin called "More Fields" It uses this to display the text in a field. '<?php meta('guys'); ?>' i need the if statement to see if it is empty and if so not display the '<option value="<?php meta('guys'); ?>">GUYS</option> ' here is what i tryed so far. '<?php if(class_exists( 'guys') && meta('guys')) :?> <option value="<?php echo meta('guys'); ?>">GUYS</option> <?php endif; ?>' it dose not show when its empty but dose not show when something is entered ether

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible solutions. The first is if have already have the value separated somewhere, then check it and then use php to replace the empty value. If you only have access to that statement in your if statement, then use a substring to extract the value and then compare it.

Comment: can you give me a example please im new to if statements

Comment: This is a little more complex for beginners? What do you need it for? Probably be easier to see if the position of the string where the end code is when empty equals a quote.

Comment: i solved the problem i changed plugins and this code now calls the text entered into the field. <?php the_field(guys) ;?>. i used this code to only display the option in the drop down if a url was entered. '<?php
 
if(get_field('guys'))
{
 echo '<option value="' . get_field('guys') . '">GUYS</option>';
}
 
?>
'

Answer (score 0):

Put your options in an array and run a foreach loop looking for an empty value:

```
//put the dropdown option in an array
$options = array('<option value="">GUYS AND GIRLS</option>',
                '<option value="http://test.com">GUYS AND GIRLS</option>');

//run a for each
foreach($options as $currentOption){
    //look for empty value
    if(!strstr('value=""', $currentOption)){
        echo $currentOption;
    }
}
```

**EDIT, BASED ON COMMENTS**

Try this, if it is possible for you to implement.

```
<?php
    if(meta('guys') != ""){
        echo '<option value="' . meta('guys') . '">GUYS</option>';
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: well im using a wordpress plugin called "More Fields" It uses this to display the text in a field. '<?php meta('guys'); ?>' i need the if statement to see if it is empty and if so not display the '<option value="<?php meta('guys'); ?>">GUYS</option> ' here is what i tryed so far. '<?php if(class_exists( 'guys') && meta('guys')) :?> 
<option value="<?php echo meta('guys'); ?>">GUYS</option>
<?php endif; ?>' it dose not show when its empty but dose not show when something is entered ether.

Comment: If it is not displaying in either case, `class_exists('guys')` may be failing the test.

Comment: yea i figured that might be the case, what should i try to check then any ideas ?

Comment: Try to dump the value and see exactly what is going on. `var_dump(meta('guys'));`

Comment: http://test.comNULL  come up with '<?php echo var_dump(meta('guys')); ?> and http://test.com is what i entered into the text field to be displayed

Comment: Hmm, sounds like a problem with the plugin itself and not what we are trying to do. Seems like a weird plugin that you are having to do this in the first place.

Comment: im thinking i need to echo the whole thing like so, echo <option value="<?php meta('guys'); ?>">GUYS</option> but when i try <?php if(class_exists( 'guys') && meta('guys')) :?> echo <option value="<?php meta('guys'); ?>">GUYS</option> <?php endif; ?> i get a error

Comment: i changed plugins and this code worked. <?php
 
if(get_field('guys'))
{
 echo '<option value="' . get_field('guys') . '">GUYS</option>';
}
 
?>
thnx for your help